# Why Are Android Q Beta 2 Symbols Not Recognized by Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-10.0

When I try using Android Studio 3.3.2 with the Android Q Beta 2 SDK, classes that are new to Beta 2 (over Beta 1) are not recognized by the Android Studio editor:

[image: Android Studio Editor, Showing Unrecognized Symbols]

However, the app builds and runs just fine. So, the *compiler* sees the symbols, but not the editor.

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, Android Studio (at least 3.3.2) is not realizing that the SDK changed, and so its indexes are out of date.

To clear up the problem, choose "File" > "Invalidate Caches and Restart" from the Android Studio main menu. This will force Android Studio to re-index the SDK and should allow those symbols to be recognized.

Comment: Can you please look into this problem I could not solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56513672/errorunable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdebugandroidtest-compileclasspath @CommonsWare